# Neo4j file system tuning for high IO

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

On my Hetzner EX40-SSD server I would like to optimize Neo4j.

I've [read](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-linux-notes.html#_file_system_tuning_for_high_io) that I can disable access-time updates for the database disk volume mount.
Since the database is on the same volume as anything else, I wonder if I can still do so?

The server is also used for hosting Nodejs, so would `noatime,nodiratime` benefit in general?

Here's my fstab file:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
/dev/md/0 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/md/1 /boot ext3 defaults 0 0
/dev/md/2 / ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Comment: Do you actually have IO issues? Also check the disk scheduler, it should be noop or deadline, not cfq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On systems with ssd `noatime,nodiratime` is a good idea. Additionally you may want to use TRIM, see e.g. https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives contains a good writeup of SSD specifics as well.

To improve read performance on Neo4j you should not worry too much with file system settings and invest in caching as documented on http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-caches.html.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont need logs file, add this to your fstab

```
tmpfs /var/log tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=0755 0 0
```

also adjust your Swapiness to make sure no swap will be used

To change swappiness setting:

```
$ su -
# nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

And add this line into sysctl.conf file.

```
vm.swappiness = 10
```

There are more tips I found from this page http://namhuy.net/1563/how-to-tweak-and-optimize-ssd-for-ubuntu-linux-mint.html